# gimme-aws-creds throws error while registering the MFA device

Tags: python, aws-credentials, gimme-aws-creds

I am trying to configure [gimme-aws-creds](https://github.com/Nike-Inc/gimme-aws-creds) with below configuration

```
[DEFAULT]
okta_org_url = https://xxxxx.okta.com
okta_auth_server = 
client_id = 
gimme_creds_server = appurl
aws_appname = 
aws_rolename = all
write_aws_creds = True
cred_profile = default
okta_username = my_okta_user_name
app_url = https://xxxxx.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/app_instance_id/something
resolve_aws_alias = True
include_path = True
preferred_mfa_type = token:software:totp
remember_device = True
aws_default_duration = 150000
device_token = 
output_format =
```

I have
Windows 10
Python `3.10.5`
pip3 `22.1.2`
gimme-aws-creds `2.4.0`

When I execute the `gimme-aws-creds --register-device` command to register MFA device I get error

> File "C:\Tools\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line
> 413, in _find_no_duplicates
> raise KeyError(f"name={name!r}, domain={domain!r}, path={path!r}") KeyError: "name='sid', domain=None, path=None"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it, I had to lower python version to 3.9.13  [Issue](https://github.com/Nike-Inc/gimme-aws-creds/issues/324)